# Can someone identify this book, where children are bred for specific jobs?

Tags: story-identification, novel

Things I remember about this book:

- Every child was selected for a certain job/career;
- If twins were born, one was always killed;
- Seeing colors for the first time (describing the color of an apple);
- Seeing war and death and poverty.

Does anyone have any idea what this book might be?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might want to change the title of your question to something more specific to your question.

Comment: "one was always killed seeing colors for the first time (...) seeing war and death and poverty" Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by this. Could you clarify it? Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds a lot like reality to me (except for the killing of twins). You sure it's SF?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That book is most certainly *The Giver* by Lois Lowry.  There are two others that she wrote along the same lines called *Gathering Blue* and *Messenger* that form a trilogy.  I loved reading them because they reminded me that in order to understand how good some things are, we have to remember how bad other things can be.

Comment: The Giver was part of a Trillogy? Wow, I never knew that. I remember reading it in grade 5. Kind of messed up.

Comment: Actually the Wikipedia link below says that it's now part of a Quartet. The last being released in 2012

Comment: It's a [movie now](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435651/), too. With The Dude playing the part of the Giver.

Answer (score 14):

The color bit sounds like [*The Giver*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver). Come to think of it, there was an early selection for careers and infanticide, as well.

Widely praised, but I found it a bit weak.

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember the exact details about senses and conditioning, but Huxley's Brave New World fits with the job-specific breeding.

Comment: That was my thought too, but it's been a bit too long since I have read it to remember all the specifics

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I though when I read the description.

Comment: Does sound like it, however I don't remember colors as being a part of the story.  There were the Alphas, the Betas, the Gammas, and the Deltas I think?  Each were bred for a specific station in life as well...there was no choice at birth of which way you went.

Comment: Yeah I thought Brave New World right away but there are distinct differences here. Never anything about twins or colors in that one.