# Book about children who can't see shapes or color

Tags: story-identification, books

Maybe the title of my question is off but anyway, I remember back in highschool of the year 2004 and read a strange book about a futuristic society. That society had children raised and taught in a weird way, if I'm not mistaken they were unable to see in color just like black white and grey, and shapes were odd to them as well, some of these kids later escaped this place and they were being hunted

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Were _all_ children raised this way, or just some of them?  Do you remember the cover art of the book or any character or place names?  How were they hunted?  (By surveillance systems, people on foot or tracking animals?)

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

This may be Lois Lowry's *[The Giver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver)*

[image: Common cover for The Giver]

(bolding mine)

> *The Giver* is a 1993 American young adult dystopian novel written by Lois Lowry. It is set in a society which at first appears to be utopian but is revealed to be dystopian as the story progresses. The novel follows a 12-year-old boy named Jonas. The society has taken away pain and strife by converting to "Sameness", a plan that has also eradicated emotional depth from their lives. Jonas is selected to inherit the position of Receiver of Memory, the person who stores all the past memories of the time before Sameness, as there may be times where one must draw upon the wisdom gained from history to aid the community's decision making. Jonas struggles with concepts of all the new emotions and things introduced to him: whether they are inherently good, evil, or in between, and whether it is even possible to have one without the other. **The Community lacks any color, memory, climate, or terrain, all in an effort to preserve structure, order, and a true sense of equality beyond personal individuality**.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/can-someone-identify-this-book-where-children-are-bred-for-specific-jobs